# portrait to landscape orientation and vice versa in different viewControllers

Tags: objective-c

How to do portrait to landscape orientation and vice versa in different viewControllers of an application that has tab bar controller and navigation controller ...

I did

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
  [[UIDevice currentDevice] setOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight];

 }
```

when i want OrientationLandscapeRight in a view and

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
   [[UIDevice currentDevice] setOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait];

}
```

when i want Portrait ..

Its working but the navigation bar is not adjusting in accordance with the orientation.

Answer (score 0):

try by using..

```
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft];
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't call this method because it is private and Apple will reject your app and you won't be able to publish it:

> `orientation`
>
> Returns the physical orientation of the device. (read-only)
>
> `@property(nonatomic, readonly) UIDeviceOrientation orientation`

If you want to set particular supported orientation for your controllers you need to implement several methods in them:

From Apple Docs: [UIViewController Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

> Handling View Rotations
>   In iOS 6, your app supports the interface orientations defined in your app’s Info.plist file. A view controller can override the supportedInterfaceOrientations method to limit the list of supported orientations. Generally, the system calls this method only on the root view controller of the window or a view controller presented to fill the entire screen; child view controllers use the portion of the window provided for them by their parent view controller and no longer participate in directly in decisions about what rotations are supported. The intersection of the app’s orientation mask and the view controller’s orientation mask is used to determine which orientations a view controller can be rotated into.
>
> You can override the preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation for a view controller that is intended to be presented full screen in a specific orientation.
>
> In iOS 5 and earlier, the UIViewController class displays views in portrait mode only. To support additional orientations, you must override the shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: method and return YES for any orientations your subclass supports. If the autoresizing properties of your views are configured correctly, that may be all you have to do. However, the UIViewController class provides additional hooks for you to implement additional behaviors as needed. Generally, if your view controller is intended to be used as a child view controller, it should support all interface orientations.
>
> When a rotation occurs for a visible view controller, the willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:, willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:duration:, and didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation: methods are called during the rotation. The viewWillLayoutSubviews method is also called after the view is resized and positioned by its parent. If a view controller is not visible when an orientation change occurs, then the rotation methods are never called. However, the viewWillLayoutSubviews method is called when the view becomes visible. Your implementation of this method can call the statusBarOrientation method to determine the device orientation.

Comment: please suggest me a way out that should be acceptable by Apple

Comment: @user1747629 you should follow instructions provided in my answer - in every controller you should implement corresponding methods to control screen orientation.